# Como colocar data e hora no nome do arquivo?

Tags: cmd, console

Como colocar data e hora em um nome de arquivo de output gerado a partir de um corte de vídeo usando ffmpeg? Já tentei algumas combinações de código mas não funcionaram.

Esse código funciona para cortar o vídeo porém o nome fica sem a pattern:

```
ffmpeg -ss inicio -i input.mp4 -c copy -t 60 -strftime 1 -segment_format mp4 parte_video%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4
```

Tenho um exemplo funcionando para meus vídeos 24/7 e um para as "fotos" porém o mesmo não se aplica para um único vídeo.

Exemplo dos vídeos 24/7:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video= camera -c:v libx264 -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 24:00:00 -segment_format mp4 -segment_format_options movflags=empty_moov meu_video%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4
```

Exemplo das fotos:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video=camera -qscale:v 1 -t 1 -strftime 1 -segment_format jpeg foto%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpeg
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: Será que isso não da certo foto%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpeg porque seria criado mais de uma foto por segundo e algumas ficariam com o mesmo nome?